# Unable to identify alphanumeric entities on LUIS

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to identify alphanumeric entities like ABC123654, ABC596879. The six numbers following ABC keep changing. This would have been easier with regex feature, but its deprecated now. I tried providing multiple values in the Phrase list and tagging these as entities, but the LUIS is not able to identify any other entities that differ from already provided ones in the phrase list. The entities are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define an `Entity`, type `Simple`, and tag many values in your utterances that match some sample distinct values. Then LUIS will be able to catch new unknown ones.

Comment: This seemed to work. But there are always some values LUIS is not able to pickup ! How do I trust such behaviour in production?

Comment: How many different values did you tag? Do you have some examples of the values tagged, and some catched / not catched?

Comment: I've tagged 10 samples. After multiple trainings, the model seems to work better. I'll update here if I see any particular cases.

Comment: Ok great. Don't hesitate to tag the most various cases of your values, to illustrate the range (especially if there is some values with a different length for example)